# Display Flex in Safari align

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have `div` block with one child element inside:

```css
.mark__btn {
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 3px;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.mark__btn span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mark__btn">
  <span>+</span>
</div>
```

So, I try to reach align center element `span` by horizontal and vertical, it works with Chrome, but not in Safari

Comment: Looks identical in Chrome and Safari to me … of course there's just a plus sign hanging in whitespace. It might look different if there was a visible border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use prefixes for Safari and other browsers in order to use display flex

```
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;  // for safari
display: flex;
```

Comment: Need I to use specific `flex-direction` for Sarafi?

Comment: no - once you use the prefix for the display - all flex properties and subproperties should be available

Comment: Safari hasn't needed a prefix for Flexbox since 2015!